# I2C read with 2 8 byte registers

Tags: c++, linux, i2c, beagleboneblack

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNqiO.png)

I'm new to using I2C and I'm stuck at attempting to read values since most data require several 8 byte data packets to be sent, something that most documentation and examples i've found online do not answer. The specific wording from the datasheet is:

"Two  message  structures  are  available  to  the  master;  a  write  command  and  a  read  command.    The write command is used to initiate an event and the read command returns the result.All commands start with the 7-bit slave address and are followed by thedata bytes.When reading responses, all data bytes should be read out together.Each command has a delay associated with it, this is required to allow the microcontroller time to process each request.During this delay, the correct response may not be returned, and commands sent during the period may be ignored.

For a write command the first data byte will determine the command to be initiated. The second byte contains  the  parameters  associated  with  that  command.  For  commands  which  have  no  specific requirement for a parameter the second data byte should be set to 0x00.

For  a  read  command,  the  first  data  byte  represents  the  most  significant  byte  of  the  result  and  the second data byte represents the least significant byte."

The command flow is also imaged below.

A command example that the datasheet has is: 
"To retrieve the data that represent the status,the command 0x01 should be sent followed by 0x00."

I've been attempting to use this library here: http://blacklib.yigityuce.com/classBlackLib_1_1BlackI2C.html

So how exactly would I implement this code correctly. Unfortunately I won't be able to conduct hardware tests for a while. Would it look like something similar to this?(assuming slave address is already set up)

```
uint8_t command = 0x01;
unit8_t parameter =  0x00;
uint8_t buffer = {command, parameter}


myi2c.writeLine(buffer,sizeof(buffer));
uint16_t data_output = myi2c.readWord(command);
```

Is it that simple? Calling on the writeLine function to call to command and data parameter, the using readWord to read the 2 bytes being outputted while calling the 7 bit salve address (command in this case)?

Comment: When I discuss I2C with people, I tell them it is like a turnstile.  While you are writing bits to the device, bits are coming back.  You will need to study the data sheet to see if the bit read from the device can be ignored when writing to the device.  Also, find out what you need to send in order to read data from the device.  Full duplex is fun with I2C!

Comment: It appears that the only data that matter is the data after a read command is issued. I'm just not sure if my code reflects that flow.Here's the datasheet for reference (starting on page 37): https://usermanual.wiki/Document/ClydeSpace20EPS20User20Manual133520RevD.710488976/view

Comment: You'll need to look at any linux drivers or beaglebone software development kits.  Sorry, I'm used to writing to the I2C chips directly (lower than the driver level).  Looks like your example uses either a linux driver or ome SDK from BeagleBone.

Comment: Yeah I might go back to a lower level and start my own library. Do you have any good references for working with an I2C or SMBus linux driver?

Comment: I don't deal with Linux drivers unless absolutely necessary.  Most embedded projects I worked on are too small for Linux.